# Password protect ASP.net site in IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis-7, web-config

I'm trying to add a password (basic authentication) to a .net website running on IIS 7
The site is in development, and it's on a staging server. Want to give it a simple user / password to access the site, to prevent the whole internet from seeing it
(Yes, I am aware basic authentication isn't secure, and the numerous other methods that could be used...)

In Web.Config I have this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/MyArea/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

I've disabled anonymous authentication on IIS for this site, however now, it just keeps redirecting to the above url.

What do I need to do to the Web.Config in order for this to work?

Comment: is this hosted outside or you have access to IIS?

Comment: hosted internally, have full access to IIS

Comment: what we use is to add  enableCrossAppRedirects="true"

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is only to prevent other users to access/view it while in development, but **if it is**, try this way:

1. Do not change anything in your current website
2. In IIS assign a new Application Pool to the application
3. In that Application Pool, set `Identity` to `ApplicationPoolIdentity` and use `Custom account`
4. Create or use an existing user on that account

Now, only that user / password can access and view the website.

Comment: would love to know why the negative vote... this works fine on our intranet while in development but we assign a AD Group instead a custom user.

Comment: i'm not sure either... however, i've done that, but it's not asking for a user / password to access the site

Comment: if you have any kind of authentication explicit in your `web.config` that will override IIS setting on the AppPool.

Answer (score 0):

As it goes, this wasn't possible.
I ended up using Helicon Ape to achieve what I wanted.

Comment: This is rubbish, you can easily control who accesses an application just using IIS!

Comment: Really? I'm all ears...... You can't mix Forms Authentication with Basic Authentication in IIS 7... not easily / without some wrapper / lot of effort